# How to use a boolean array to skip expensive calculations of elements in array?

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray, short-circuiting

Is there a way in numpy to use a boolean array to skip calculations of certain elements in an array? I'd like it to skip the evaluation of `expensive * arr` whenever the corresponding element in `bool_arr` is `False`.

```
  results = bool_arr & (expensive * arr)
```

This code does not short-circuit and the `and` operator is unfit because it does not evaluate elementwise, is there another elegant solution available in numpy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `bool_arr` to work on a subset of the array, given `expensive` can thus run on a small set of values, like:

```
results = bool_arr
results[bool_arr] = expensive * arr[bool_arr]
```

Comment: Some `ufunc` take `out` and `where` parameters to do this sort of masking.  I haven't looked at the relative speed advantages.